# How to properly display three images each with their own caption in the same horizontal space evenly spaced apart

Tags: horizontal-alignment, minipage

As of now, we are grouping three mini-pages (each with an image and a caption) into one figure, shown using the code below:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}
    \frame{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./Image1.jpg}}
    \caption{Dummy}
\endminipage\hfill
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}
    \frame{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./Image2.jpg}}
    \caption{Dummy}
\endminipage\hfill
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}
    \frame{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./Image3.jpg}}
    \caption{Dummy}
\endminipage\hfill
\end{figure}
```

And this was providing the desired result:
[image]

Until the last sequence of three images that pretty much uses the same code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}
    \frame{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./Image4.jpg}}
    \caption{Dummy}
\endminipage\hfill

\minipage{0.32\textwidth}
    \frame{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./Image5.jpg}}
    \caption{Dummy}
\endminipage\hfill

\minipage{0.32\textwidth}
    \frame{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./Image6.jpg}}
    \caption{Dummy}
\endminipage\hfill
\end{figure}
```

Which displays those images like this:
[image]

What could possibly causing this inconsistency and how do we resolve it?

Comment: In the second example, you have empty lines between the minipages. Remove them or put a `%` to comment them out.

Comment: "Pretty much" is relative... :)

Comment: @Werner thanks for the laugh lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between the code snippets is that the latter has blank lines between the images. Blank lines introduce paragraph breaks, which necessarily lead to the `minipage`s being separated *vertically*.

If you want the code spread out, insert a `%` (comment) on the blank lines (effectively removing them from the output).

```
\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}{0.32\textwidth}
    \frame{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
    \caption{Dummy}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  %
  \begin{minipage}{0.32\textwidth}
    \frame{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
    \caption{Dummy}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  %
  \begin{minipage}{0.32\textwidth}
    \frame{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}}
    \caption{Dummy}
  \end{minipage}%
\end{figure}
```

Above I've updated the placement of `\hfill` so the images are pushed to the text block boundary.

Comment: Thank you. I feel quite silly that it was something so simple.

Comment: Most people who make this mistake use subfigures, which would be easier to find than `align minipages`.